# Merging two unordered_maps with overlapping keys

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to merge two `std::unordered_map`: `mapA` and `mapB`, while keeping priority for items from `mapA` if both maps contain the same key.

Is there an elegant way of doing this (rather then validating each key.. my maps contain a large number of elements)?

Example:

```
mapA = {{"sugar",0.1},{"salt",0.2}}
mapB = {{"sugar",0.3},{"pepper",0.4}}
```

The result I would like to have is:

```
result = {{"sugar",0.1},{"salt",0.2},{"pepper",0.4}}
```

Ignoring the key-value `{"sugar",0.3}` from `mapB`

Thanks.

Comment: My first thought would be to insert the result of `std::set_difference` with a custom comparator into `mapA`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
auto result = mapA;
result.insert(mapB.begin(), mapB.end());
```

The `insert` member functions of `unordered_map` do nothing if the key already exists within the container.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/o2agrm)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is tagged C++11, but for completeness it seems worth mentioning that C++17 added the `merge()` function if you don't care about keeping mapB intact. `merge()` moves all of the elements whose keys are not in mapA from mapB to mapA. If a key are in mapA, mapA remains unchanged for that element and the element remains in mapB.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/merge

Answer (score -2):

Since `std::unordered_map` is unsorted, there is no other way.  You will have to loop over each element in `mapB` and attempt to insert it in `mapA`.  Existing elements in `mapA` will not be inserted.